# What is J.J. LaRoche's dark secret?

Tags: character, the-mentalist

In the season 3 of [The Mentalist](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1196946/), Patrick Jane threatens J.J. LaRoche to expose his secret if he doesn't give him his suspect list. LaRoche's secret is *something* he keeps in a tupperware in his safe. Jane actually bluffs since he knows only of the existence of the tupperware, but has apparently no idea of its actual content.

Later on, Jane says that *whatever J.J. LaRoche's dark secret is, it must be horrible*.

Is there any clue to what J.J. LaRoche's dark, horrible secret is?

Comment: I think it is either something really embarrassing or really tragic. I doubt it's anything nefarious. But hey all will be revealed in the penultimate episode of season 5.

Comment: I believe it could be the tongue but, an injection was used to help cut out the tongue
and kirkland used an injection to kill Mr. Leannon. But hey it could of been the tongue and JJ la roche is red john...what else could it of been.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Laroche's Tupperware box is the tongue of the man who raped his mother for 2 hours straight, Scott Sanay(sp). The day before his trial, Laroche broke into his apartment while he slept, injected him with a sedative and cut out his tongue. According to the rapists mother Judith Sanay, "they never found his tongue."

Viewers find out in 21st episode of the 5th season (S05E21), "Red and Itchy."

Comment: Watch Lisbon's expression when judith Sanay said "they never found his tongue."

Answer (score 5):

I understand that's not the answer you were looking for, but **there's no real clue about LaRoche's dark secret**.

By the way, we know a lot about its personality and that could bring some consideration to the "discussion". 
He lives in a big house fitted with monothematic ornaments and only a cat as a friend.
He's extremely detailed and obsessive. He has good feelings. He probably experienced a tragic lost and maybe he feel responsible for it. 
His secret could be someway related to this profile.